# My phpAdmin says 'no tables in database'

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I've built a site locally on Mac using MAMP. All looks fine. BUT, My phpAdmin says 'no tables in database'. It's empty. What have I done wrong? And how is it that I can see and work on the website locally if the database says it's empty? Is there anything I can do so that I can load usable files to a remote server to go live?

Comment: If I understand correctly you have already built a site, locally – without using a database. Why would you now want to add a database? Or did you actually use any kind of cms / blog system ß

Comment: Thanks, I've used Wordpress. As I said I'm a novice, do I not need a database to load to the remote server to go live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a Database and Tables offcourse!

Comment: Thanks, I've used Wordpress. As I said I'm a novice, can this be done even though the site is already built?

Comment: If you are installing WordPress, then WordPress will automatically import the tables for you, you will have to create a database in PHPMYADMIN and put that details in wp-config.php - It's easy dude

Comment: Um. Ok. Sounds good, as I said, I'm a novice. I'll give it a go. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, you are not looking at the same database than the one from which your Wordpress is working. It could also be that the username is not the same as the one used by your Wordpress site.